# How to remove the "unnamed" row from dataframe in python?

Tags: python

```
        Unnamed: 0           Unnamed: 1  ... Unnamed: 12  Unnamed: 13
3   Instrument                Start  ...        data          err
4           2D  2020-05-13 00:00:00  ...         NaN          NaN
5         SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0133993 -7.44403e-07
6         SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0159991  -8.8884e-07
7         SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...    0.017799 -9.88834e-07
8         SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0199989 -1.11105e-06
9         SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0229987 -1.27771e-06
10        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0245986 -1.36659e-06
11        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0311983 -1.73324e-06
12        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...    0.035998 -1.99989e-06
13        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0329982 -1.83323e-06
14        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0309983 -1.72213e-06
15        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0349981 -1.94434e-06
16        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0399978  -2.2221e-06
17        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0423476 -2.35265e-06
18        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0499972 -2.77762e-06
19        SWAP  2020-05-15 00:00:00  ...   0.0459974 -2.55541e-06
```

In this dataframe, the first row contains unnamed items and it doesn't have any index. How can I  remove it?

Comment: how you creating the dataframe

Comment: How are you creating this dataframe? It might be a better idea to fix the issue there rather than modifying it afterwards.

Comment: I read it from spreadsheet

Comment: How is the spreadsheet formatted? What kind of file is it .csv, .xlsx? How are you reading it?

Comment: post the code you have tried for creating dataframe

Comment: data = pd.read_excel("Swap.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet2")

Comment: I try to convert it to dataframe afterwards, but I cannot drop the unnamed rows.